# Redirect Firebase Push notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an App that has number of vendors providing offers and discounts on their product.
I am able to send notification but i want user to be redirected to a details page where vendor's information from firebase cloud firestore is dynamically loaded to that particular details page.

I want to know how do I send firebase collection documents with notification

Comment: add document id on notification payload and get data of that document on the page you're redirecting the user from notification tap.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should send collection name as a data in notification so that when received notification  you can extract collection name from data.